# Free shipping - minimum order value without tax

Tags: magento-1, shipping, free-shipping

is there a way to declare the minimum order value in system->configuration->shipping->free shipping without tax?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this be to create you own custom module which duplicate the free shipping module code or copy Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping to local

Take a look at [create shipping method module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module)

```
/**
 * FreeShipping Rates Collector
 *
 * @param Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request
 * @return Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result
 */
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

    $this->_updateFreeMethodQuote($request);

    if (($request->getFreeShipping())
        || ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >= $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
        ...
```

Change `$request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax()` to `$request->getPackageValueWithDiscount()`